# checking in table row is exist or not?

Tags: php, mysql

Here it comes more than one array at a time. I want to check that if any row is exist then that row have to not save in table.

```
function insertcsv(){

            $db = new DB();
            $csvArr = $db->csvToArray($this->csvfile);

            foreach($csvArr as $csvArrData) {
                $checksku = "Select * form product where sku='".$csvArrData['sku']."'";//check this sku is already in table 
                $resultsku = $db->query($checksku);

                if(!empty($resultsku)){
                    echo "<pre>"; print_r($resultsku); exit;
                } else {
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO `product`(`name`, `description`, `short_description`, `sku`, `weight`, `visibility`, `price`, `tax_class`, `image`, `quantity`, `stock_availability`, `category`, `product_status`, `status`, `date_time`) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($csvArrData['name'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($csvArrData['description'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($csvArrData['short_description'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($csvArrData['sku'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($csvArrData['weight'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($csvArrData['visibility'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($csvArrData['price'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($csvArrData['tax_class_id'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($csvArrData['image'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($csvArrData['qty'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($csvArrData['is_in_stock'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($csvArrData['_category'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($csvArrData['status'])."','Y',now())";

                    $result = $db->query($sql);
                }
            }
            return($result);    
        }
```

This code gave me blank page. why?

Comment: You tell us, what errors are you getting

Comment: This gave me blank page. but i gave duplicate row. I am checking with sku attribute.

Comment: Turn on error reporting, place `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);`at the top of your page

Comment: Can you add the code `echo print_r($resultsku, true); die();` before the line `if(!empty($resultsku)){` and tell us what is printed on the webpage ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This code gave me blank page. why?

You are getting blank page because you got displaying php runtime errors disabled but your your script "crashes" because of invalid SQL query -> you typed `form` wher you need `from`:

```
$checksku = "Select * FROM product where sku='".$csvArrData['sku']."'";//check this sku is already in table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function insertcsv(){

        $db = new DB();
        $csvArr = $db->csvToArray($this->csvfile);

        foreach($csvArr as $csvArrData) {
            $checksku = "Select * from product where sku='".$csvArrData['sku']."'";//check this sku is already in table 
            $resultsku = $db->query($checksku);

            if(!empty($resultsku)){
                echo "<pre>"; print_r($resultsku); exit;
            } else {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO `product`(`name`, `description`, `short_description`, `sku`, `weight`, `visibility`, `price`, `tax_class`, `image`, `quantity`, `stock_availability`, `category`, `product_status`, `status`, `date_time`) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($csvArrData['name'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($csvArrData['description'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($csvArrData['short_description'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($csvArrData['sku'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($csvArrData['weight'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($csvArrData['visibility'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($csvArrData['price'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($csvArrData['tax_class_id'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($csvArrData['image'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($csvArrData['qty'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($csvArrData['is_in_stock'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($csvArrData['_category'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($csvArrData['status'])."','Y',now())";

                $result = $db->query($sql);
            }
        }
        return($result);    
    }
```

You didn't notice it until now my frnd..

just Copy this and paste it to your source.

Regds..